# Не нажимаются Checkbox [PyQt5]

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Есть дизайн, вот скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`checkable` - включен, но когда запускаю саму программу, невозможно ставить галочки в `checkbox'ах`, подскажите что делаю не так?

Код дизайна:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 40, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 70, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 100, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 130, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")
        self.checkBox_5 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 160, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName("checkBox_5")
        self.checkBox_6 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 190, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName("checkBox_6")
        self.checkBox_7 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 220, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_7.setCheckable(False)
        self.checkBox_7.setObjectName("checkBox_7")
        self.checkBox_8 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 250, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_8.setCheckable(True)
        self.checkBox_8.setObjectName("checkBox_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 10, 151, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1000, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menu)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action1.setObjectName("action1")
        self.action2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action2.setObjectName("action2")
        self.action3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action3.setObjectName("action3")
        self.action4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action4.setObjectName("action4")
        self.action5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action5.setObjectName("action5")
        self.action6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action6.setObjectName("action6")
        self.action7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action7.setObjectName("action7")
        self.action8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action8.setObjectName("action8")
        self.action9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action9.setObjectName("action9")
        self.action10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action10.setObjectName("action10")
        self.action1_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action1_2.setObjectName("action1_2")
        self.action2_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action2_2.setObjectName("action2_2")
        self.action3_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action3_2.setObjectName("action3_2")
        self.action4_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action4_2.setObjectName("action4_2")
        self.action5_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action5_2.setObjectName("action5_2")
        self.action6_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action6_2.setObjectName("action6_2")
        self.action7_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action7_2.setObjectName("action7_2")
        self.action8_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action8_2.setObjectName("action8_2")
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action1_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action2_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action3_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action4_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action5_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action6_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action7_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action8_2)
        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Анализ по Шварцу:"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать снимок"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор"))
        self.action1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 снимок"))
        self.action2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.action3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.action4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.action5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.action6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.action7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.action8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.action9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.action10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
        self.action1_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.action2_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.action3_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.action4_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.action5_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.action6_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.action7_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.action8_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код самой программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

from dis import Ui_MainWindow              # <-------

class Example(QMainWindow):                                #(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.image = ""

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.action1_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image2)
        self.ui.action2_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image3)
        self.ui.action3_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image4)
        self.ui.action4_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image5)
        self.ui.action5_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image6)
        self.ui.action6_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image7)
        self.ui.action7_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image8)
        self.ui.action8_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image9)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.image)        #("0.bmp")
        self.lbl = QLabel()                 #(self)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)

#        self.setLayout(hbox)
#        self.move(100, 200)
#        self.show()

    def load_image2(self):
        self.image = "1.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image3(self):
        self.image = "2.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image4(self):
        self.image = "3.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image5(self):
        self.image = "4.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image6(self):
        self.image = "5.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image7(self):
        self.image = "6.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image8(self):
        self.image = "7.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image9(self):
        self.image = "8.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста программу, которую вы запускаете.

Comment: Все, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore       # +++

from dis import Ui_MainWindow              

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.image = "im.png"

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
# +++        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)                         
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                  
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)                
        self.lbl  = QLabel(self.centralWidget)

        self.ui.action1_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image2)
        self.ui.action2_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image3)
        self.ui.action3_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image4)
        self.ui.action4_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image5)
        self.ui.action5_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image6)
        self.ui.action6_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image7)
        self.ui.action7_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image8)
        self.ui.action8_2.triggered.connect(self.load_image9)
# +++         
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox,   alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_3, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_4, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_5, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_6, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_7, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ui.checkBox_8, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.initUI() 
# +++        
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)        

    def initUI(self):
        #hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.image).scaled(500, 500,  
                                     QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                     QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.lbl.show()

    def load_image2(self):
        self.image = "lo.jpg" #"1.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image3(self):
        self.image = "ll.jpg" #"2.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image4(self):
        self.image = "im.png" #"3.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image5(self):
        self.image = "4.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image6(self):
        self.image = "5.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image7(self):
        self.image = "6.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image8(self):
        self.image = "7.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()

    def load_image9(self):
        self.image = "8.ini"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли как нибудь при нажатии на CheckBox выполнять действие? Например при нажатии на CheckBox, изменять значения переменной?

Comment: Все возможно посмотрите например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931361/python-pyqt5-how-to-treat-guis-checkboxes-as-separated-object   Поэкспериментируйте, будут вопросы - выставляйте пример и пишите что не получается, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все получилось :)

Comment: Я бы хотел узнать, почему если использовать ваш код, то Label, расстановка CheckBox'ов скинулись, а картинка начала занимать меньший размер? И возможно ли как нибудь это исправить?

Comment: С размером разобрался, а вот куда делся Label, не могу понять.